# Apache Nutch Error

Tags: apache, solr, hbase, nutch, web-crawler

I am completely new to Nutch Solr, and Hbase. I have installed the following

apache-nutch-2.2.1,

hbase-0.9.4, and

solr-3.6.2.

I am currently running OS X Mavericks and I have Java 1.7 installed

Every other thing seems to work fine except when I try crawling, I get some few errors with actually no work done which is shown below:

```
mac:local engrsnmusa$ bin/crawl urls/seed.txt TestCrawl http://localhost:8983/solr/ 2
```

InjectorJob: starting at 2014-05-07 21:09:56

InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: urls/seed.txt

2014-05-07 21:09:56.720 java[2865:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore

InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.memory.store.MemStore as the Gora storage class.

InjectorJob: total number of urls rejected by filters: 0

InjectorJob: total number of urls injected after normalization and filtering: 1

Injector: finished at 2014-05-07 21:10:02, elapsed: 00:00:06

Wed 7 May 2014 21:10:02 BST : Iteration 1 of 2

Generating batchId

Generating a new fetchlist

GeneratorJob: starting at 2014-05-07 21:10:07

GeneratorJob: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.

GeneratorJob: starting

GeneratorJob: filtering: false

GeneratorJob: normalizing: false

GeneratorJob: topN: 50000

2014-05-07 21:10:08.129 java[2874:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore

GeneratorJob: finished at 2014-05-07 21:10:12, time elapsed: 00:00:04

GeneratorJob: generated batch id: 1399493402-24778

Fetching :

FetcherJob: starting

FetcherJob: batchId: 1399493402-24778

Fetcher: Your 'http.agent.name' value should be listed first in 'http.robots.agents' property.

FetcherJob: threads: 50

FetcherJob: parsing: false

FetcherJob: resuming: false

FetcherJob : timelimit set for : 1399504217796

2014-05-07 21:10:18.207 java[2881:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore

Using queue mode : byHost

Fetcher: threads: 50

QueueFeeder finished: total 0 records. Hit by time limit :0

-finishing thread FetcherThread0, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread1, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread2, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread3, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread4, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread5, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread6, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread7, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread8, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread9, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread10, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread11, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread12, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread13, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread14, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread15, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread16, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread17, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread18, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread19, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread20, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread21, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread22, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread23, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread24, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread25, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread26, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread27, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread28, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread29, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread30, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread31, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread32, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread33, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread34, activeThreads=0
-finishing thread FetcherThread35, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread36, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread37, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread38, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread39, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread40, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread41, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread42, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread43, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread44, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread45, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread46, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread47, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread48, activeThreads=0

Fetcher: throughput threshold: -1

Fetcher: throughput threshold sequence: 5

-finishing thread FetcherThread49, activeThreads=0

0/0 spinwaiting/active, 0 pages, 0 errors, 0.0 0 pages/s, 0 0 kb/s, 0 URLs in 0 queues

-activeThreads=0

FetcherJob: done

Parsing :

ParserJob: starting

ParserJob: resuming:    false

ParserJob: forced reparse:  false

ParserJob: batchId: 1399493402-24778

2014-05-07 21:10:36.065 java[2888:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore

ParserJob: success

CrawlDB update for TestCrawl

DbUpdaterJob: starting

2014-05-07 21:10:44.649 java[2895:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore

DbUpdaterJob: done

```
Indexing TestCrawl on SOLR index -> http://localhost:8983/solr/
```

SolrIndexerJob: starting

2014-05-07 21:10:47.965 java[2902:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore

SolrIndexerJob: done.

```
SOLR dedup -> "http://localhost:8983/solr/"
```

2014-05-07 21:10:51.160 java[2909:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore

Wed 7 May 2014 21:10:54 BST : Iteration 2 of 2

Generating batchId

Generating a new fetchlist

GeneratorJob: starting at 2014-05-07 21:11:12

GeneratorJob: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.

GeneratorJob: starting

GeneratorJob: filtering: false

GeneratorJob: normalizing: false

GeneratorJob: topN: 50000

2014-05-07 21:11:13.955 java[2919:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore

GeneratorJob: finished at 2014-05-07 21:11:19, time elapsed: 00:00:06

GeneratorJob: generated batch id: 1399493454-2657

Fetching :

FetcherJob: starting

FetcherJob: batchId: 1399493454-2657

Fetcher: Your 'http.agent.name' value should be listed first in 'http.robots.agents' property.

FetcherJob: threads: 50

FetcherJob: parsing: false

FetcherJob: resuming: false

FetcherJob : timelimit set for : 1399504284866

2014-05-07 21:11:25.322 java[2930:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore

Using queue mode : byHost

Fetcher: threads: 50

QueueFeeder finished: total 0 records. Hit by time limit :0

-finishing thread FetcherThread0, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread1, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread2, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread3, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread4, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread5, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread6, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread7, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread8, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread9, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread10, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread11, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread12, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread13, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread14, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread15, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread16, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread17, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread18, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread19, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread20, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread21, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread22, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread23, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread24, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread26, activeThreads=1

-finishing thread FetcherThread25, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread27, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread28, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread29, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread31, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread32, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread33, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread30, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread34, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread35, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread36, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread37, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread38, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread39, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread40, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread41, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread42, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread43, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread44, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread45, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread46, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread47, activeThreads=0

-finishing thread FetcherThread48, activeThreads=0

Fetcher: throughput threshold: -1

Fetcher: throughput threshold sequence: 5

-finishing thread FetcherThread49, activeThreads=0

0/0 spinwaiting/active, 0 pages, 0 errors, 0.0 0 pages/s, 0 0 kb/s, 0 URLs in 0 queues

-activeThreads=0

FetcherJob: done

Parsing :

ParserJob: starting

ParserJob: resuming:    false

ParserJob: forced reparse:  false

ParserJob: batchId: 1399493454-2657

2014-05-07 21:11:41.723 java[2937:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore

ParserJob: success

CrawlDB update for TestCrawl

DbUpdaterJob: starting

2014-05-07 21:11:49.314 java[2944:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore

DbUpdaterJob: done

```
Indexing TestCrawl on SOLR index -> http://localhost:8983/solr/
```

SolrIndexerJob: starting

2014-05-07 21:11:52.281 java[2951:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore

SolrIndexerJob: done.

```
SOLR dedup -> http://localhost:8983/solr/
```

2014-05-07 21:11:55.373 java[2958:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore

mac:local engrsnmusa$

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: i am stuck in same problem, please answer if you came up with the solution

Comment: I still haven't found any solution. Please keep me posted if you have a breakthorugh

Comment: There was a problem with the hbase-0.94, upgrading the version fixed the above issue.

Comment: Thanks... Did you install Hadoop before Hbase?

Comment: Upgrading to hbase-0.98 gave me following error:

InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: urls/seed.txt
InjectorJob: org.apache.gora.util.GoraException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "34440g� �E5PBUF

Comment: I came across that error but I can't recall how I went around it. I suggest, you study the compatibility of the versions of nutch, hbase and solr. I just found out that hbase is built on hadoop. So a good starting point is to install hadoop. You can try homwbrew to help you with the installs.